# Entity Framework 1-To-1 with cascade delete enabled

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, cascading-deletes

I'm using EF 4.3.1 and want to create an attachment object and keep its binary data separately. So, I created two tables in the database: Attachments and AttachmentData. Here is a [screenshot](http://cache.hostmyjpg.com/e6d7961668_db.png) or their relationships.

And here are my classes:

```
public class Attachment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public AttachmentData Content { get; set; }
}

[Table("AttachmentData")]
public class AttachmentData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] Data { get; set; }
}

public class AttachmentConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Attachment>
{
    public AttachmentConfig()
    {
        HasRequired(att => att.Content)
            .WithRequiredPrincipal()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete();

        Property(att => entity.Id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        Property(entity => entity.Name).IsRequired();
    }
}
```

We use repository pattern to access database:

```
public class Repository
{
    private readonly Context _db = new Context(); 

    public Attachment Add(string fileName, byte [] data)
    {
        var att = new Attachment
                      {
                          Name = fileName,
                          Content = new AttachmentData {Data = data}
                      };

        _db.Documents.Add(att);
        _db.SaveChanges();

        return att;
    }

    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        /* Try to find in local context
         * otherwise exception might appear:
         * "An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. 
         * The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key."
         */
        var att = _db.Documents.Local
            .FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == id) ?? new Attachment {Id = id};

        _db.Entry(att).State = EntityState.Deleted;            
        _db.SaveChanges();            
    }
}
```

I wrote a simple test to see if I can add and delete attachments:

```
public void Can_Add_And_Delete()
{
    const string fileName = "FileName.tst";
    var data = new byte[] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    /*************
    * Works fine *
    *************/
    var cont = new Context();
    var att1 = new Attachment
               {
                   Name = fileName,
                   Content = new AttachmentData {Data = data}
               };

    cont.Documents.Add(att1);
    cont.SaveChanges();

    cont.Documents.Remove(att1);
    cont.SaveChanges();

    /********************** 
    * Throws an exception *
    *********************** 
    * The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because
    * one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change 
    * is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to 
    * a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new 
    * relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned
    * another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted. 
    */

    var repo = new Repository();
    var att2 = repo.Add(fileName, data);
    repo.Delete(att2.Id);
}
```

From the detailed description of thrown exception it is clear that problem is caused by an existence of AttachmentData entity in the context. But I thought a context would be smart enough to delete AttachmentData once Attachment state is set to deleted (since 1-to-1 relation is configured). If it's not the case, then what's the point of using WillCascadeOnDelete() method? Is it for proper db relation generation only and C# side can't get any benefits of it?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I’m facing precisely the same problem now.